# api.test.sabre.com times out and gives no response (multiple different endpoints)

Tags: rest, sabre

Every URI/endpoint for api.test.sabre.com gives no response and just times out. Not sure if there is a status endpoint but I think this would be a good addition just to see if you can actually hit the api.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/sws-crt-as.cert.havail.sabre.com/` url (assuming Air product, CERT environment).

All links (and more) can be found here: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments

Answer (score 0):

For REST this is the environments listing:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/environments